# Taylor and Francis Manuscript Status "Under Review"

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission

Does this status mean it has been sent to referees? Or is could it still be desk rejected?

Comment: It can also be a desk reject. I speak from experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under review implies it has been sent out for peer review and has passed the initial check. T & F primarily uses ScholarOne Manuscripts but also have their own electronic submission system. There may be slight differences between these but I would think they are set up similar to each other. I am familiar with the ScholarOne system.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this status means that the manuscript has passed the in-house review and has been sent out to the reviewers.